How to fetch submodules from local repo
I'm working on support for a new machine, and have to change a few changes to one app, which is in a git repository with a couple of submodules. In order to make changes without having to commit them to the repository, I switched the url to the local repository:
SRC_URI += gitsm://my-local-path/myapp;protocol=file

The issue comes with the submodules, as they are being fetched from the remote repository yet, not finding the local commit.

ERROR: myapp-git-AUTOINC+5cb44c0abb do_fetch: Fetcher failure:
Unable to find revision 90d482fd1645daa8249fe0ef94ed465f064110ab in
branch  even from upstream
ERROR: myapp-git-AUTOINC+5cb44c0abb
do_fetch: gitsm: submodule download failed: FetchError Fetcher failure
for URL:
'gitsm://git/repos/libs/lib;protocol=ssh;name=lib;subpath=lib;nobranch=1;bareclone=1;nobranch=1'.
Unable to fetch URL from any source.

As you can see, it is still using "protocol=ssh", how can I fix this/workaround it?

try with this post and with this other. In this posts there is set the branch parameter which could be useful in your case. But sorry I'm not sure that it is enough!
